# (Python) How can I revert a string of bytes back to the original string?

Tags: python, string, encoding

I have been parsing websites and turns out I saved the content to json files in a less than preferable way, and can't seem to reverse engineer the process. Basically I have saved the BeautifulSoup tags as following

```
r = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
article = soup.find("article")

b = article.encode()
c = str(b) 
# save c in json structure using json.dump(f)
```

and I want to be able to obtain article given c.

Using codecs seemed to almost get me there:

```
import codecs
codecs.getdecoder("unicode_escape")(c)[0]
```

However the scandinavian letters å,ä,ö doesn't decode properly.

**In short:**

Input:

```
'b\'<article> \\n L\\xc3\\xa4s bl.a. om Gasporox nya m\\xc3\\xa4tkoncept f\\xc3\\xb6r tr\\xc3\\xa5g, en intervju med styrelseledamoten Per Nystr\\xc3\\xb6m och nyheter fr\\xc3\\xa5n GPX Medical om bland annat projekten Sinuslight och Neo-Lung.\\n</article>''
```

Desired Output:

```
<article>
Läs bl.a. om Gasporox nya mätkoncept för tråg, en intervju med
styrelseledamoten Per Nyström och nyheter från GPX Medical om 
bland annat projekten Sinuslight och Neo-Lung.
</article>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to evaluate the `b''` value and then decode it with `UTF-8`

```
import ast
x = "b\'<article> \\n L\\xc3\\xa4s bl.a. om Gasporox nya m\\xc3\\xa4tkoncept f\\xc3\\xb6r tr\\xc3\\xa5g, en intervju med styrelseledamoten Per Nystr\\xc3\\xb6m och nyheter fr\\xc3\\xa5n GPX Medical om bland annat projekten Sinuslight och Neo-Lung.\\n</article>'"

x = ast.literal_eval(x)

result = x.decode("utf-8")
```